# how can I set my bash window title to the last command that ran?

Tags: bash

I'd like the title of my terminal windows to show the last command that ran. It'd be handy for finding the terminal that's running Mongrel in Dev/Test/Prod etc (for testing rails apps).

I tried this code:

```
if [ "$SHELL" = '/bin/bash' ]
then
    case $TERM in
         rxvt|*term)
            set -o functrace
            trap 'echo -ne "\e]0;$BASH_COMMAND\007"' DEBUG
            #  export PS1="\e]0;$TERM\007$PS1"
         ;;
    esac
fi
```

At least, I think that's the code that I tried. It did work, but it caused some strange behavior, like window titles that would get stuck in a loop until I hit Ctrl C when changing directory to a symlink.

What's a reliable way to set my window title to the last command that was run?

Comment: [This script](https://gist.github.com/resilar/ade1e0311755e7e0a402cbecc836f486) only displays commands while they're running, which might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the `xtitle` tool:

```
sudo apt-get install xtitle
lastcmd() { xtitle $(history 1 | cut -c8-); }
PROMPT_COMMAND=lastcmd
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using only standard commands**

```
lastcmd() { LASTCMD=$(history 1 | cut -c8-); echo -ne "\e]2;$LASTCMD\a\e]1;$LASTCMD\a"; }
PROMPT_COMMAND=lastcmd
```

**Test it**

```
echo 'This echo command should be displayed on my window title'
```

**Timestamp**

To also display the time of the last command, set the environment variable `HISTTIMEFORMAT`:

```
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%c
```

See `man date` for a complete list of date/time formats.

To disable the timestamp prefix on window title:

```
unset HISTTIMEFORMAT
```

**Persistence**

A good place to put these two lines is in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: So I'd put this in my .bashrc, correct?

Comment: Nope, I added that to my bashrc and started a new terminal and I got this at my prompt: `]0;echo -ne ""]2;reload]1;reload~> ` and my window title is `cut -c8-`. That's what it looks like when I start the terminal. Sorry, that didn't work.

Comment: Correct: `~/.bashrc` is a good place to put that.
Hummm... this works fine for me on Lubuntu10.10/`bash` at home and on my `PuTTY`/`bash` at work. Please can you provide a portion of your ~/.bashrc and `$PS1`, `$PS2`, `$PS3` and `$PS4`? (you can edit your question). Then, I can test on my computer. Cheers.

Comment: @jcollum I can test on my computer, but I need to be as close as possible to your environement. Therefore, please provide some info as your `.bashrc` and `PSx` variables. Cheers.

Comment: @olibre I have this working for local terminals, is there a way to use this with remote ssh connections too? While i am working on a remote dev server I often tail the error logs but there are several log files, I want to be able to see which file im tailing in the title bar.

Comment: Hi @Chris; You may add my function `lastcmd()` and `PROMPT_COMMAND=lastcmd` in your remote `~/.bashrc`. If you have many many remote hosts, you may also consider using an Ansible playbook to deploy that on your remote hosts. Does this idea meet your requirements? Please, let me know if I can help further. Cheers

Comment: I will give that a go later on. I have some maintenance to do on the dev server as the production server was just updated so once thats completed I will try this out.